# Basic formal systems

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

I'm studying history but I always loved math. So my question is, what math topic is simple to learn, but still fullfills my need to think mathematically? I have some experience in basic group-theory and some physics, mostly self taught. My own idea is to learn about formal mathematical systems, but the ones I found are either too complex or too simple. Or maybe combinatorics or geometric algebra are enought. Not sure. It should be a simple but deep topic that is easy to learn and be mostly self contained.

Comment: Try to find a course or book on Introduction to Mathematical Proofs or Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning. There are books and probably online courses for these topics. They are meant for those whose mathematics education has been centered on computation and wish to transition to the study of rigorous mathematics.

Comment: An obvious choice for a historian would be Euclid's Elements, which reigned as *the* mathematical textbook for over 2000 years. Alexander studied it in his youth, Lincoln studied it while serving as a Senator, reading it at night while his collegues snored in the bunkhouse (Congress was much different then). Though several flaws have been uncovered over the millenia, it still gives an excellent treatment of geometry and logical deduction.